# Varios threads en c#

Tags: c#, hilos

Hola estoy haciendo una aplicación en la cual necesito que ejecute en segundo plano una llamada a una Api:

```
Main{
    Metodo();
} 
Metodo(){
   for(i=0,i<100,i++){Metodo2(i)
}
Método2(int i){    
    apiThread2 = new Thread(() => LlamadaAUnaApi);
    apiThread2.IsBackground = true;
    apiThread2.Start();
}
```

La cosa es que la aplicación termina antes de que terminen los Threads de ejecutar, he intentado agregarlos a una lista de Threads pero cuando el `Método2` finaliza se ponen a no activo `apiThread2`. Se que si al final de `método2` hago `apiThread2.Join();` espera a ese thread pero me gustaría que mientras `Metodo()` siguiese con sus cosas y querría hacer el `Join` al final del Main recorriendo la lista de Threads.

¿Es esto posible de alguna forma?

Comment: Has probado a ver si usando un Backgroundworker te sirve?

Comment: Yo siempre aconsejo lo mismo. Nunca utilizar la clase `Thread` en C#. Es complicada y ni siquiera gente experta es capaz de preveer efectos no deseados. C# cuenta con clases mas amigables, `BackgroundWorker` como comenta @Veelicus o la mas moderna `Task`

Comment: @Pikoh pero Task he probado y tampoco me hace `LlamadaAUnaApi` todas las veces que debería, igual hace un 80% de ellas pero por lo que veo no todas.

Comment: Estas seguro que no es un problema del api al que llamas? todos suelen tener un limite de conexiones concurrentes, y meterle 100 de golpe me parece demasiado

Comment: ¿Has pensado en utilizar Task y asyncronos?, con ese par puedes hacer hasta parallelismo de forma bastante rapida.

Comment: @Pikoh seguro que no es la Api porque estoy gestionando las respuestas que me da y todas son ok, por lo que aprecio son los últimos valores los que no llegan, al finalizar la ejecución del programa no espera a las Task activas?

Comment: Por defecto no. Si usas `Task`,tienes que esperarlas por ejemplo con `Wait` o `WaitAll`. @SergioParraGuerra te acaba de dar una solucion usando `async/await` que yo creo que es la mejor solucion.

Answer (score 4):

Para mí una buena solución es emplear `async/await`. Te paso un ejemplo.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(() => Metodo()).Wait();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public async static Task CallApiAsync(int apiCall)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Llamada a API {apiCall}");
        }

        public async static Task Metodo()
        {
            List<Task> jobs = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                Task job = CallApiAsync(i); // se asigna una Task
                jobs.Add(job);
            }

            await Task.WhenAll(jobs); // esperar la ejecución de las llamadas a API
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Corrección se debe reemplazar:
`Console.WriteLine($"Llamada a API {apiCall}");`
Por:
`Console.WriteLine("Llamada a API {0}", apiCall.ToString());`

Comment: Es correcto el código que he puesto si empleas C#6.0 al menos. He aplicado lo que se conoce como string interpolation.